# Netty Client: request-response in same future

Tags: sockets, netty

I'm trying to implement a Netty client which will send a TCP request and receive a response in the same `Future`. The code is below

```
public void sendMessage(String msg) {
  Future<Channel> future = simpleChannelPool.acquire();

  future.addListener((FutureListener<Channel>) f -> {
    if (f.isSuccess()) {
      Channel ch = f.getNow();

      ChannelFuture channelFuture = ch.writeAndFlush((msg + " " + now() + lineSeparator()));

      channelFuture.addListener(writeFuture -> {
        if (writeFuture.isSuccess()) {
          System.out.println("Channel write successful");
          // how to READ data here?
        }
      });
      // Release back to pool
      simpleChannelPool.release(ch);
    } else {
      System.out.println("Failed to acquire a channel");
    }
  });
}
```

The part that I'm missing is how to read the data after successful write, line `if (writeFuture.isSuccess()) {...`. Basically I need to wait until next read is finished.

Also, given Netty's asynchronous nature, is it a right tool for request/response protocols?

Netty version used: **4.1.39.Final**.

The complete code is available [here](https://github.com/dome313/netty-connection-pool/tree/request-response-netty-client/src/main/java/se/lolotron/connectionpool).